# Irrationality of $ \frac{1}{\pi} \arccos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This paper [arxiv.org/pdf/0911.1933](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.1933) discusses, regarding the irrationality of certain trigonometric functions. Recently, i encountered this problem which says states the given function, $$ f(n)=\frac{1}{\pi} \arccos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$$ is irrational for every odd $n \geq 3$. But i couldn't find the proof anywhere. Can anyone provide me with the proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could find the proof in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=CuTpgZaLahkC&pg=PA40): *Proofs from the Book* by Martin Aigner, Günter M. Ziegler, Karl H. Hofmann, pages 40-41

Comment: Don't you think it's more appropriate to write that as a comment?

Comment: @Asaf: It really doesn't matter! I got what i wanted, and Baudrillard deserves credit for that!

Comment: @Asaf Karagila In one of the previous posts by Chandru1 I've written the source in the comments, but since the question gathered a lot of comments, it got lost in "see n other comments" line. I think that the source of the problem with a complete solution is important enough to be left as an answer. I've made it community wiki, as you can see.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer. No idea why people insist on this being a comment. So what if Baudrillard didn't come up with it him/herself?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to prove that a certain angle is irrational with respect to $\pi$, most of the times it follows from the following simple result:

**Lemma**: If $n, k \in {\mathbb Z}$ and $n>0$ then $2 \cos( \frac{k \pi}{n})$ is an algebraic integer.

**Proof**: We show that there exists a $P_n \in {\mathbb Z}[x]$ monic of degree $n$ so that

$$2 \cos(nx) = P_n(2 \cos(x)) (*) \,.$$

$P_0(X)=2, P_1(X)=X$ and using

$$\cos((n+1)x)+ \cos((n-1)x)=2 \cos(x) \cos(nx) \,,$$

we get the recurence:

$$P_{n+1}(x) = XP_n(x)-P_{n-1}(X) \,.$$

Now $(*)$ follows by induction, and then Lemma follows immediately.

---

Now, back to the problem. Suppose by contradiction $\frac{1}{\pi} \arccos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$ is rational. Then we can find $n, k \in {\mathbb Z}$ and $n>0$ so that

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \arccos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{k}{m} \,.$$

Hence

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}= \cos(\frac{k}{m}) \,.$$

Then, by Lemma, $2\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is an algebraic integer, and hence is its square.
But then $\frac{4}{n}$ is an algebraic integer and rational, thus integer.

This shows that $4$ divides $n$.

Comment: Very nice! $\text{ }$

Comment: @user9176:  if you want boldface, just put it between double asterisks:  \*\*this is bold\*\* creates **this is bold**

Comment: Feel like there are some typos? (i) Shouldn't $P_0(x)$ be defined as $P_0(x) = 2$? For it to satisfy the induction hypothesis $2\cos(0x) = P_0(2\cos(x))$.
(ii)  Suppose by contradiction $\arccos(1/\sqrt{n})/\pi$ is rational, why the ratio $k/n$ where the denominator is itself $n$? Am I missing something or should it just be $p/q$? (it doesn't affect the resulting proof, seems like.)
(iii) Hence statement: why did the argument pick up a factor of $2$? Shouldn't the argument be $\cos(p\pi/q)$.

Comment: @nervxxx fixed it