# Points on a 2D plane spanned by a turtle graphics system

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, euclidean-geometry, symmetry

Suppose you have a [turtle graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics) system with a set "turning angle" $\delta$, in which the turtle can execute three commands:

- $F$: Go forward, by unit length, in the current direction. (The initial direction is irrelevant.)
- $+$: Turn $\delta$ degrees to your left.
- $-$: Turn $\delta$ degrees to your right.

(For example, [L-systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) are drawn using a very similar setup.) I will write $+^n$ and $-^n$ to mean "turn $n\delta$ degrees to your left/right", where $n$ is an integer.

Given $\delta$, I want to know which points on the plane the turtle can reach. Specifically, I'm interested in whether the set of reachable points is **dense in $\Bbb R^2$** or not.

---

If $\delta/2\pi$ is irrational, the [set of reachable angles is dense in $[0, 2\pi]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903142/for-an-irrational-number-a-the-fractional-part-of-na-for-n-in-mathbb-n-is) Informally, this means you can move arbitrarily small distances by making really sharp turns: find some integer $n$ so that $n\delta$ is *almost* 90 degrees. Then $+^nF-^{2n}F+^n$ will move a very tiny bit in the current direction. Since there's then a way to move arbitrarily small distances at arbitrary angles, I'm quite sure this means the set of reachable points is dense in $\Bbb R^2$.

If $\delta/2\pi$ is rational, then $\delta = (a/b)2\pi$ for some irreducible fraction $a/b$. Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, there is some [$n$ so that $n\delta = (1/b)2\pi$ (modulo $2\pi$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), so we can reduce the problem to the case $\delta = 2\pi/b$ for some positive integer $b$.

Here's where I'm stuck. I know that for e.g. $b=4$, the turtle can only turn at 90° angles, and is obviously stuck on a square lattice; similarly, if $b=3$ or $b=6$ the turtle is stuck on a triangular lattice moving only at 120° or 60° angles. $b=1$ or $b=2$ means the turtle is stuck on a given line.

How can I prove that the set of reachable points is **not** dense in the plane for precisely these values of $b$?

---

(I think what I'm looking at can be described as the **additive** subgroup of $(\Bbb C, +)$ generated by the *b*th roots of unity: the roots $z_0, z_1 \dots z_{b-1}$ correspond to the turtle commands $F$, $-F+$, $-^2F+^2$, etc. For which $b$ is this group's underlying set dense in $\Bbb C$? Therefore, I've tagged this question [group-theory](/questions/tagged/group-theory).)

Comment: If ${+}F{-^2}F{+}$ is an irrational multiple of $F$ (i.e. $\cos\delta$ is irrational) then the set of reachable positions along the initial direction is dense, and you're pretty much done, no?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808355).

Comment: The answer linked by ccorn is exactly what you're looking for, because the additive subgroup of $\Bbb{C}$ generated by the $b$-th roots of unity is precisely $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_b]$, where $\zeta_b$ is any primitive $b$-th root of unity. By the way, the tag [tag:number-theory] is more appropriate than the tag [tag:group-theory]...

Comment: I don't understand Qiaochu Yuan's answer at all (in the question ccorn linked). He writes: "a subgroup $A$ of a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$ such that $A$ spans $V$ is either discrete or dense in a subspace of $V$, and in the first case it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ where $n = \dim V$." What about $\Bbb Z \times \{1\} \leq \Bbb R^2$ -- the former is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, but $\dim R^2 = 2$, no? EDIT: of course, this group doesn't span $\Bbb R^2$, nevermind.

Comment: I sort of understand, now. However, I still don't know how to combine my condition ("$\alpha$ is a primitive root of unity") with Qiaochu Yuan's ("either $\alpha$ has degree 3 or has degree 2 and is not an algebraic integer") in order to find the exact values for $b$.

Comment: Is it as simple as saying: suppose $\alpha$ is a primitive $b$th root of unity. Then $\deg \alpha = b/2$ if $b$ is even, since $\alpha^{b/2} = -1$ is a minimal polynomial, and $\deg \alpha = b$ otherwise, since $\alpha^b = 1$ is a minimal polynomial. Thus $\deg \alpha = 2$ only for $b=4$ and $\deg \alpha = 3$ only for $b=3$ and $b=6$?

Comment: I feared that backward moves might not be possible for odd $b$, but since the sum of all $b$-th roots of unity, including $1$, is zero, one just needs to add up all $b$-th roots of unity except $1$ to get $-1$. So indeed we are looking at $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_b]$, even if $b$ is odd.

Comment: @ccorn: By the way, could you touch on how what Rahul said relates to this approach, too? Is "$\cos \delta$ rational" a necessary and sufficient condition in my case?

Comment: In our case, $\deg\zeta_b=\phi(b)$ where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_totient_function). There are very few values $b$ where $\phi(b)\in\{1,2\}$; I suppose you can find them all.

Comment: @ccorn: I see. Where's $\{1, 2\}$ coming from? Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $b=1$, the turtle can only reach equidistant points within a ray;
it cannot move backwards, so that case does not yield a group.

In the following I will assume that $b$ is an integer greater than $1$.

Let the turtle start at $0$ in the complex plane with direction $1$.
There are exactly $b$ possible directions for the turtle,
and we can represent those directions as
$\zeta_b^k = \exp(\mathrm{i}k\delta)
= \exp\left(\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}k}{b}\right)$
for $k\in\{0,\ldots,b-1\}$.

For each direction $\zeta_b^k$ we can maintain a step counter
$a_k\in\mathbb{N}_0$ that is incremented whenever the turtle steps
in that direction.
Then the turtle's position can be given as
$$z = \sum_{k=0}^{b-1} a_k\zeta_b^k$$
I claim that the set of all possible $z$ remains unchanged
if we allow negative integer values for the $a_k$ as well.
In other words, the equivalent of backward moves is possible.
This can be deduced from the fact that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \zeta_b^k = 0\quad\text{for $b>1$}$$
(Note that this requires $b>1$ which is why that case had to be separated.)
Concretely, let $a_{\text{min}} = \min_{k=0,\ldots,b-1} a_k$, then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \underbrace{(a_k - a_{\text{min}})}_{\geq0}\,\zeta_b^k
= \underbrace{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} a_k\zeta_b^k\right)}_z
- a_{\text{min}}\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \zeta_b^k}_0 = z$$
So we can make all step counters nonnegative by adding $-a_{\text{min}}$
to all of them without changing the turtle position $z$.

As a result, the set of all possible turtle positions can be identified
with $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_b]$, the ring of all polynomials in $\zeta_b$
with integer coefficients.

[Another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808355)
unveils the cases when $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_b]$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$:
Since $\zeta_b$ is an algebraic integer (it solves $X^b - 1 = 0$),
$\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_b]$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if
the degree of (the minimal polynomial of) $\zeta_b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$
is greater than $2$.

The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the
[cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)
$\Phi_b$, its degree is $\phi(b)$ where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_totient_function):
$$\phi(b) = b\prod_{\substack{p\text{ prime}\\p\mid b}}\frac{p-1}{p}$$

$\phi(b)$ is a positive integer,
so we just need to exclude those $b$ that have $\phi(b)\in\{1,2\}$.
These are $b \in \{1,2,3,4,6\}$; to see that there are no more $b$,
note that

- if $b$ had a prime divisor $p$ greater than $3$, then
  $\phi(b)$ would be divisible by $p-1$ which is greater than $2$;
- if $b$ were divisible by $2^3$ or $2^2\cdot3$,
  then $\phi(b)$ would be divisible by $4$; and
- if $b$ were divisible by $3^2$,
  then $\phi(b)$ would be divisible by $6$.

Consequently, $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_b]$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if
$b\not\in\{1,2,3,4,6\}$.

@Rahul has indicated another approach which may seem easier to grasp:

Obviously, $b>2$ is necessary and sufficient for the turtle to move in more than
one dimension. So let us assume $b>2$.
Note that $+F--F+$ moves forward $2\cos\delta$.
Replacing $F$ with $(+F)^{b-1}+$ moves backward instead.
So we can effectively move in the current direction with any step size
from the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $1$ and $2\cos\delta$.
Therefore, if $\cos\delta\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, the set of available
step sizes is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Combined with the ability to move in
more than one dimension once $b>2$, this makes the set of reachable turtle
positions dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if $\cos\delta$ is irrational.

In [yet another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845/irrationality-of-frac1-pi-arccos-frac1-sqrtn/39336?s=9|0.1628#39336),
a useful lemma has been given:

> If $\frac{\delta}{\pi}$ is rational, then $2\cos\delta$ is an algebraic integer.

**Proof:** Assuming $\frac{3\delta}{\pi}=\frac{c}{n}$
with $c,n$ coprime integers and $n>0$, we have
$$2\cos(n\delta)=2\cos\frac{c\pi}{3}=u
\quad\text{for some}\quad u\in\{\pm1,\pm2\}$$ and
$$2\cos(n\delta) = D_n(x)\quad\text{where}\quad x = 2\cos\delta\tag{*}$$
where the $D_n(x)$ are [*Dickson polynomials of the first kind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson_polynomial)
(with second parameter $\alpha=1$).
Their essential property is
$$D_n\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right) = z^n + \frac{1}{z^n}$$
Setting $z=\exp(\mathrm{i}\delta)$ yields $(*)$.
Those Dickson polynomials can be defined recursively as
$$\begin{align}
D_0(x) &= 2 \\
D_1(x) &= x \\
D_n(x) &= x\,D_{n-1}(x) - D_{n-2}(x) &&\text{for $n>1$}
\end{align}$$
By induction we can see that the Dickson polynomial $D_n$ has integral
coefficients, degree $n$ and is monic for $n>0$.
The same holds for $D_n(x) - u$ (at least for $n>0$ which we assume),
a root of which is $x=2\cos\delta$.
Therefore $2\cos\delta$ is an algebraic integer.

Consequently,
if $\cos\delta$ is rational, then $2\cos\delta$ must be an integer.
Since $\cos\delta$ is bounded to not exceed absolute value $1$,
the only possibilities are $2\cos\delta\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$
which correspond to $b\in\{2,3,4,6,1\}$.
All other $b$ therefore yield irrational $\cos\delta$
and result in turtle position sets that are dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$.